# LinuxLive USB does not save settings

Tags: live-usb, settings

I am new to Linux.

I have used/tried all of these utilities:
"LinuxLive USB  live-usb-install-2.5.2", "LinuxLive USB Creator 2.8.28", "unetbootin-windows-603", "Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2"
to successfully create a 16GB USB that boots linux live.

I have used linux mint 16 cinnamon and mate 32 and 64 bit, also ubuntu 14.04 64 bit to be the os.

USB was formatted to FAT32.

I have used persistence up to 4GB

There is a casper-rw file

I have edited the append line in syslinux.cfg to have persistence at the end of the line

F6 is not an option and boot up does not ever show boot in persistence, always just the try without installing etc.

No matter what I do, When I boot my laptop using my live-usb, and then change the settings (e.g. desktop wallpaper) and then reboot, the settings go back to default. How do I make the live-usb save the settings?

(I have successfully installed Linux on my USB and that works but then it runs slowly and only works on my laptop and not any other machine.)

I cannot think of anything else to do.  Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

3 Days Later
Looks like it must be something to do with my main laptop - cannot seem to do anything with it.
On the other desktop computer it works fine - goes through and saves to the persistence file!  Little needs to be done there except create a user and make it the default to open with, which I have done.
I created the USB on the main laptop and even after saving with desktop it still opens without anything allowed to save to persistence.
I can only assume it is a limitation within the BIOS.
At least I can use it how I wanted to on the desktop.

Comment: Is the laptop using [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) ?

Comment: Yes it has UEFI Activated for the SSD hard drive installed as my C Drive for Windows

Comment: Turnde off UEFI (Disabled) and now the laptop works the same as the desktop.  Windows works as well (maybe UEFI is only necessary when installing Windows 7 onto an SSD hard disk).

So now just have to get Mint the way I like it... but that's another story.
Thanks